# Big amount of data and RAM

Tags: c++, memory, vector, ram

I'm testing my program on laptop with 8GB RAM, but it will has to pass tests on pc with 2 GB RAM (program is in C++98). I read 'big' amounts of data ( n <= 15 000), n is number of points (everyone has x,y), I need one (n-1)(n-2)/2 vector > and one n(n-1)/2 table to store distances between every two points. Besides that I need few n length tables (lets say around 10).
Vector isn't declared dynamically and the table is declared using "new" as global variable.

- What will happen when there will me not enough RAM for my program (
  for example for n=15000)?
- Will normally work, while using swap or not? Is it better not to
  create table with distances and count distances only when they'
  are needed?
- I'm trying to use "delete()" as much as i can, but I read that
  will won't free RAM instantly. Is there any simple ways to tore data 
  from table and vector, while saving RAM?

Comment: Have you calculated a precise number to indicate how much memory your program needs? tbh n==15000 is actually quite small, but the amount of memory required depends on the size of each object. Note that architecture (32-bit vs 64-bit) will affect overall memory required. Your statement "trying to use `delete()` as much as you can" also raises alarm bells that you have holes in your understanding of memory management. So any problems you encounter will more likely be due to mistakes in your code that the underlying memory needs of your app. Basically: _Your question is far too broad._

Comment: I just use delete when something allocated with new isn't needed later. And when n==16000 ( i wanted to try n>15000, but still around it) it takes 1.5-2GB of RAM. I chcked it using "free -m"

Comment: And??? Your comment doesn't address the problem that your question is too broad. The first bullet point by itself is borderline too broad for SO. What happens is affected by 32/64 bit, by OS, by whether your app is large address aware (if 32 bit windows), by how you've implemented your error handling. Second bullet point, who can say? You've provided no code. Third bullet, also very broad and no code. It's not clear what you're asking there. .... _Fix your question and you're more likely to get useful answers._